# How can I increment and decrement a unicode character by 1?

Tags: c#, .net, unicode

I am writing a small program with a label and 2 buttons. The label is initialized with a unicode character, for example `"\u221A"` (√).

I would like 1 button to increment the unicode value of the label, say to `"\u221B"`, then to `"\u221C"`, etc, and another to decrement it, say to `"\u2219"`, then `"\u2218"`, etc.

I have no idea where to begin, and have googled for quite a while. I've tried doing stuff myself, but none of it compiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char` is a numeric type.  You can add and subtract numbers from it, then cast it back to `char` and create a string from it.

Comment: That helped. Using what you told me I have `tbUnicode.Text = ((char)(char.Parse(tbUnicode.Text[0].ToString()) - 1)).ToString();`, but it's rather long. Is there a shorter way I can keep it in one line?

Answer (score 1):

Without code I can't give a specific answer. However perhaps this is what you're thinking of:

```
char ch = label.Text[0]; // assumes label is not empty; get first character of string
++ch; // increment; use -- to decrement instead
label.Text = ch.ToString(); // back to string
```

Add your own error handing and range checking. Also keep in mind that many code points aren't defined and many others won't display in certain fonts.